# Converting a file stored in local path to a multipart file and sending it on REST gives error code 415

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to send a file stored in my system over a REST controller(Spring) which accepts Multipart File as an input.

For this I have used the following code:

```
    String catalinaHomePath = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
                String pathToSave = catalinaHomePath+"\\"+packageName;

                File dest = new File(pathToSave);
                //Path path = Paths.get(pathToSave);



                //String originalFileName = "file.txt";
                File file = new File(pathToSave);
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
                MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
                        file.getName(), "text/plain", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

====================================================

The controller which accepts this request is
as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadTosca", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public StatusBean uploadTosca(@ModelAttribute("command") ToscaRequestBean beanObj)
```

With requestBean containing following parameters:

```
    private String templateType;


        private String userId;


        //For TOSCA
        private MultipartFile toscaFile;
```

The code used for sending this request over REST is as follows:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod(requestType);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

                        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

I am getting error code 404. Instead of success.

Comment: Changed the content-type defined while converting the file to multipart file. Still getting the same error. Please note:  That the file I am trying to upload is a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for sending a multipartfile from one method over REST API:

```
String accessToken = UserUtils.getAccessToken();
        fileObj = new File (multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        multipartFile.transferTo(fileObj);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fileObj);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        if(category == "catalog")
        {

        if(type == "toscaPackage")
        {
            LogManager.getLogger().info("TYPE IS: "+type);
            builder.addPart("toscaFile", fileBody);
            LogManager.getLogger().info("Tosca File is: "+fileBody);
            builder.addPart("userId", new StringBody(parent.getString("userId"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        }
            builder.addPart("templateType", new StringBody(parent.getString("templateType"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        }



        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        if(url != null) {

            if(isSecureChannel)
            {
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection).setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });


            }
            else
            {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            }

            // urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                
        }
```